# jquery hide and show is not working when the div is called outside td block of table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-tables

Here when I click on `No` the text box should get hidden but it is not happening. When I put the same `div` inside the `td` from where I am calling the `onclick` event it is working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <script>   
        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">   
    </script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#btn1").click(function(){
                $("#data").show();
            });
            $("#btn2").click(function(){
                $("#data").hide();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Table</th>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" id="btn1" name="gate" value="N" checked>Yes</input>
            <input type="radio" id="btn2" name="gate" value="E" >No</input>  
        </td>
    </tr>

    <div id="data" style="padding-top: 10px">
        <tr>
            <th>GATE</th>
            <td><input type="text" name="gate1" value=gate1 size="20"></td>
        </tr>
    </div>
</table> 
</html>
```

Comment: `div` is not allowed inside `tr` list!

Comment: not a valid markup

Comment: Share the fiddle if you have one.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid as the `div` cannot be a child of `table`. The browser removes that element, hence your `show()` and `hide()` calls appear to do nothing. Fix your HTML and the JS code will work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are putting a `div` inside the table- you should not do that. Try this code:

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#btn1").click(function() {
        $(".data").show();
      });
      $("#btn2").click(function() {
        $(".data").hide();
      });
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Table</th>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" id="btn1" name="gate" value="N" checked/>Yes
      <input type="radio" id="btn2" name="gate" value="E" />No
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="data" style="padding-top: 10px">
    <th>GATE</th>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="gate1" value=gate1 size="20">
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="data" style="padding-top: 10px">
    <th>GATE</th>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="gate2" value=gate2 size="20">
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>

</html>
```

Comment: This thing worked. But how can i hide multiple rows currently it is hiding only the next row with the id="data".

Comment: @user3101852 Edited the above answer so that you can show/hide multiple columns now. Please let me know your feedback on this. Don't forget to mark as accepted too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn1").click(function(){
  $("#data").show();
 });
 $("#btn2").click(function(){
  $("#data").hide();
 });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">   
</script>

</head>

<table>
<tr>
<th>Table</th>
<td>
  <input type="radio" id="btn1" name="gate" value="N" checked>Yes</input>
  <input type="radio" id="btn2" name="gate" value="E" >No</input>  
</td>
</tr>
<tr  id="data">
<th>GATE</th>
<td><input type="text" name="gate1" value=gate1 size="20"></td>
</tr>


</table> 
</html>
```

Comment: This thing worked. But how can i hide multiple rows currently it is hiding only the next row with the id="data".